# By what mechanisms does Amoxicillin break down while in storage?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

[image]

Assuming the following conditions, what are the primary mechanisms of breakdown?

- Dry powder form (not in any pill or packaging)
- Stored in a glass bottle
- Not exposed to light
- 22C ambient temperature

Comment: For a start, I suggest to look into the documentation that comes with the medication. What does it say? Of course the active ingredient may degrade, but also other parts of the formulation. Intact packaging is obviously important.

Comment: Each is different, and even different manufacturers of the same formulation could have differing storage recommendations. The best you can do is research each online, e.g., https://medlineplus.gov/druginfo/meds/a685001.html#storage-conditions , and look for commonalities.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik These guidelines seem tailored to consumers. If that's the case they're not going to say "store at -80C" even if the drug would last indefinitely at that temperature. I'm looking for more a chemistry angle on this. They've already published a shelf life so they have no reason to explain how to keep it longer than that. Furthermore there have been some studies showing that a lot of emergency stockpile medications in the US are needlessly thrown out for exactly this reason.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7040264/

Comment: I'm not looking for recommendations, I'm looking for the mechanisms of breakdown and how they can be minimized.

Comment: Extreme temperature can cause also mechanical breakdown of tablet assembly, what can cause big impact on absorption of the drug, considering absorption rate and it's place in digestion tract.

Comment: @Poutnik Ok, but lets just consider the drug compounds themselves for now.

Comment: For compounds, there is universal advice of low T, darkness and low humidity, with need of proper temperation in both ways. ( To prevent high or condensing package humidity when cooled down too fast even with desiccant. And similarly condensing external humidity at shocking warm up.) // Particular advises are highly specific.

Comment: P.S.: So are mechanisms of degradation.

Comment: One can't generalize about conditions. For example, low temperatures may cause a medication *delivered as an emulsion* to separate through freezing, or crack the shell of a capsule as contents expand, contract or crystallize.

Comment: This gives some ideas what happens in the presence of water and oxygen: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0045653513002245

Comment: Why does nobody speak about Drew's inquiry, namely the mechanism of breakdown ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Karsten's reference to [Gozlan et al., Chemosphere (2013) 91(7), 985-992](https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0045653513002245) appears to show that the major breakdown route under the reported wet conditions was to open the beta-lactam ring hydrolytically to form the corresponding penicilloic acid.

In any other conditions, the strained 4-membered beta-lactam ring seems on many reckonings still likely to be the most reactive (~unstable) part of the molecule, together with its fused thiazolidine ring partner.

Under the storage conditions mentioned in the question (i.e. 'dry' but in an unspecified hence presumably ordinary bottle), there may be a shortage of water but probably not a complete absence. So it might be expected that some hydrolytic decomposition to the penicilloic acid would happen unless the 'dry' character has been taken even further by freeze-drying and storage in sealed ampoules.

Under freeze-dried conditions, there might still be residual room for slower ring-opening reactions between amoxicillin molecules.